# Geth always return null

Tags: go-ethereum

I did setup Geth in fast mode, but its always return null. I waited more than week for full sync.

Whats issue can be ?

I am trying test with this code

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('http://MY-IP-HERE');

const blockNumber = 18611462

web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber)
  .then((block) => {
    console.log(block);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```